# Worker on Python2, and client on Python3 in Celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, python-2.x

I'm trying to have the worker run on Python2, and client on Python3.
I notice that if I launch client from Python3, the worker code too seems to run on Python3, instead of Python2.

How can I resolve this? My worker code lies on Python2, and client using it has to run on Python3?

This is how I've set it up.

#### VirtualEnv1: Python2.7.12 (tasks.py)

```
from celery import Celery
import time

app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://localhost')

app.conf.update(
    task_serializer='json',
    accept_content=['json'],  # Ignore other content
    result_serializer='json',
    timezone='Europe/Oslo',
    enable_utc=True,
)

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    time.sleep(5)
    print "Trying to process task" # This can run only on Python2, and not Python3
    return x + y
```

Execution command:
**celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -c 1**

#### VirtualEnv2: Python3.5.2 (client.py)

```
from celery import Celery
from tasks import add
import time

app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://localhost')

app.conf.update(
    task_serializer='json',
    accept_content=['json'],  # Ignore other content
    result_serializer='json',
    timezone='Europe/Oslo',
    enable_utc=True,
)

result = add.delay(4, 8)
result.get()
```

And this is the error I get upon executing client.py (in python3)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tasks import add
  File "/home/vishal/work/yobi/expr/tasks.py", line 17
    print "Trying to process task"
```

Isn't this unexpected? I would have guessed that the worker code should run on Python2, and not Python3.

Comment: The worker code isn't run by the client, but it is imported and therefore its syntax is evaluated. I think this case should work if you added `from __future__ import print_function` to tasks.py and write it in py3 style.

Comment: Also, your client code should only import the task and not instantiate the Celery object.

Comment: Long ago I played with celery tasks in such way that client software (i.e. software that would insert task to the queue) would only have a header of task method (i.e. body-less method) and implementation was delivered within project that was loaded by celery process. Client would not see the implementation of tasks that are executed within celery process. Long ago this used to work, I'm not sure if it still will.

Comment: @Greg0ry: Yes this works even now. Had discovered this technique after posting the question. Saw your comment now..